# Ёлочки вместо кавычек в css

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при вводе в `input` или `textarea`, кавычки " " были ёлочками `« »`. Пытался использовать атрибут `lang="ru"`. Ничего не выходит, кавычки все равно вводятся такие " ".

Comment: Вводится то, что пользователь вводит, независимо от языков, css и прочей дребедени. Вводит лапки — будут лапки, вводит ёлочки — будут ёлочки. Если вы хотите автозамену лапок на ёлочки, используйте javascript

Comment: @andreymal Красиво разъяснил....)))

Comment: @andreymal, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy не является ответом на вопрос, потому что я не рассказал, как именно делать автозамену (и не собираюсь, мне лень)

Comment: @andreymal, является, потому что то, как делать замену на js он не спрашивал.